# Comparing the Gaussian curvatures of two surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization

**EDIT:** I figured it out. I computed the Hessian incorrectly the first time (missed a crucial minus sign). Thanks to everyone who helped.

Suppose that we have two orientable regular surfaces, $A$ and $B$, such that $B$ is fully contained in the interior of $A$, and $A$ is has positive Gaussian curvature everywhere (for the purposes of this post, we can assume that $A$ is a sphere, even though $A$ is not necessarily a sphere in my problem).

Given a point $q\in A$, we find the point $p=p(q) \in B$ which is closest to $q$. Suppose further that we can find a $q \in A$ minimizes the distance $\Vert q - p(q) \Vert$ on $A$.

**The problem:** I would like to prove that the Gaussian curvature of $B$ at $p(q)$ is at least as great as that of $A$ at $q$.

I was thinking of taking two curves parametrized by arclength: $\alpha(t)$ on $A$ with $\alpha(0) = q$, and $\beta(s)$ on $B$ with $\beta(0) = p(q)$, and then using the fact that 
\begin{equation}
\nabla (\Vert \alpha(t) - \beta(s) \Vert^2) |_{t=0, s=0} = 0,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\det \left(\nabla^2 (\Vert \alpha(t) - \beta(s) \Vert^2) |_{t=0, s=0}\right) \geq 0,
\end{equation}
since $(q, p(q))$ minimizes $\Vert q - p(q) \Vert^2$ by construction. The gradient being zero allows me to conclude that, given that the minimal distance is not zero, the vector $q-p(q)$ is normal to both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (which is expected due to our construction). In fact, I should be able to just take the normal vector to $A$ at $q$, which should also be normal to $B$ at $p$.

I was hoping that the inequality involving the Hessian would give me some fruitful inequality concerning the normal curvatures of $A$ and $B$ with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but I was unsuccessful in finding anything that would allow me to reach the wanted conclusion.

Could someone provide me with a hint on how to proceed, or suggest a different way to go about this?

Comment: Rather than just the Gaussian curvature, maybe you can directly prove that all principal curvatures of $B$ are at least as large as the curvature $1/r_A$ of $A$, by considering curves along the principal curvature directions of $B$. Also, why don't you treat the pair $(q,p)$ as a function of $p\in B$ rather than of $p\in A$, since the map $p\mapsto q=r_A p/\|p\|$ is much simpler?

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your comment. The surface $A$ is not necessarily a sphere in the problem I'm working on, I just said that we could assume that $A$ is a sphere for simplicity, and then I could probably adjust the method to work more generally. (That being said, we know that the Gaussian curvature of $A$ is positive.) For the first part of your comment, this is what essentially what I was hoping to find using the inequality for the determinant of the Hessian, but I was unable to see from it that the principal curvatures of $B$ are going to be greater than the principal curvatures of $A$.

Comment: You mean that $B$ is fully contained in the interior of $A$ (assuming $A$ is a closed surface, that makes sense)?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, of course! I will edit that.